# onYouTubePlayerReady not being called after load with swfobject

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

What am I doing wrong? The YouTube player replaces the #player element, but `onYouTubePlayerReady` is never called.

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function() {
    alert('success!');
    console.log('yt player loaded!', arguments);
}

window.onload = function () {
    swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/S57AWoY6zDQ?version=3&enablejsapi=1',
    'player', 800, 600, '8', null, null, 
    { allowScriptAccess: true }, { id: 'myYTplayer' });
};
```

live code: http://jsfiddle.net/patricklorio/GyMN5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ allowScriptAccess: true }` should be `{ allowScriptAccess: 'always' }`